# JS classes extending

Tags: javascript, class

Could you explain why this code will console.log:

```
B A
B B
```

I don't exactly know how constructors and super() work in this case

```js
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.name = 'A'
        this.getName()
    }
    getName() {
        console.log("A " + this.name)
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.name = "B";
        this.getName()
    }
    getName(){
        console.log("B " + this.name)
    }
}

new B
```

Comment: Because calling `super` executes the constructor of A - which sets the `name` property to the value `A`, and then the `getName` call logs `"B " + this.name`. `this` _is_ `B`, all the way through.

Comment: `this.getName()`, or more generally, `this` refers to the current instance. If you override `getName()` in `B`, it will become the instance method

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** The key thing to remember is that `this` refers to an *instance of `class B`*, not `class A` (even when calling `super()`). So `this.getName()` will invoke the method defined in class B, and the method from class A is ignored.

It's useful to think about this code in chronological order. Here's the rundown on what happens:

1. Both classes are declared with their respective methods.
2. `new B` invokes the `constructor` in `B`
3. `super()` is called, invoking the `constructor` in `A`
4. `this.name = 'A'` sets the `name` attribute to "A"
5. `this.getName()` in `A` invokes the `getName` from `B` (remember: `this` refers to an instance of `class B`, not `class A`).
6. `getName` from `B` **outputs "B A"** (recall that `this.name` is still "A" from step 4)
7. `A`'s `constructor` is completed, and we return back to `B`'s constructor
8. `this.name = 'B'` sets the `name` attribute to "B"
9. `this.getName()` invokes the `getName` from `B` (remember: `this` refers to an instance of `class B`)
10. `getName` from `B` **outputs "B B"** (recall that `this.name` is "B" from step 8)
11. B's constructor returns, and the program exits

Comment: You're welcome @Matushini! On StackOverflow we express thanks by [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269681/how-can-i-thank-this-website), so you don't need to comment "Thank you" going forward :). This also ensures that other people who search for the same question can see the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

First "B A" because super() invokes the constructor of A, which logs "A" followed by the value of this.name, which is 'A'. Then "B B" because the constructor of B sets name to 'B' and logs "B" followed by the value of this.name, which is 'B'.

Comment: _"which logs "A" followed by the value of this.name"_ - no, it's `B` followed by `this.name`.

Answer (score 0):

When `super()` is called, `this` refers to `class B`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#description

Although the definition of `getName` is overridden in `class B`, the method from  `class A` is not destroyed - it can be accessed from `class B` via a `super` function calll.

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
       this.name = 'A';
       this.getName();
    }
    getName() {
        console.log("A " + this.name);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "B";
        super.getName();
    }
   getName() {
        console.log("B " + this.name);
    }
}

new B;
```